# Generating a key to use with AES

Tags: encryption, aes, keys, symmetric, password-based-encryption

I'm going paperless, and I want to encrypt the documents that I scan. I'd like to use CommonCrypto to perform AES-XTS encryption on each file. I'm a software engineer, and I like the idea of being able to write my own wrapper around the library. However, I am not a crypto expert by any means. If I understand IVs and salting correctly, is it possible to use one long passphrase to generate a unique encryption key for each file? Also, is this general approach a good idea, or should I go in a different direction?

Comment: Short answer: yes, it's completely fine to do that... using salting and IVs correctly is a big part of what matters here. I see no reason that XTS would be any harder or more impractical than CBC... the only restriction is that you're not going to be encrypting many GBs of data with one key, which I can't imagine you are. One simple way to generate 256 bit keys (assuming you want to do that) is probably just to use HMAC-SHA256(passphrase,nonce), although [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) wasn't designed for this, it's a working approach.

Comment: I'll be encrypting lots of smaller files. Doesn't the salting let me take a passphrase and turn it into a unique encryption key for each file? Or am I understanding that wrong?

Comment: yes a unique salt makes the KDF output different for the same password

Comment: Based on that, here's my plan: highly entropic pass phrase. Use that phrase with a salt to generate a unique key for each file. Randomly generate an IV for each file. This is where I'm unsure. Do I store the IV and salt with the encrypted file?

Comment: You're not wrong, you just don't have the whole picture. Maybe if I said, for each file, you use HMAC_SHA256(passphrase,salt) it would be more clear (or use a KDF). Essentially if you mix the pass-phrase and a unique salt for each file, you'll get a different key each time... [in some cases a nonce, simply means an salt, only used once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174131/what-is-the-difference-between-hash-salting-and-noncing). It's essential that you don't use the same salt more than once.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. One passphrase + unique salt per file = unique key for each file. Correct? And am I correct in storing the salt and IV with each file?

Comment: you store the salt and IV with the file. However.. XTS mode does not use an IV but rather a disk sector number, and is not a preferred method for file encryption

Comment: Oh, I see. I was mistaken. I see a lot of discussion about the different modes to use. In some cases I see that CBC is bad, in others I see it's fine. It all runs together. What's preferred for file encryption?

Comment: The current "standards" for file encryption are GCM and OCB mode. CBC and CTR are fine as long as you use them correctly and add a MAC. ANY mode can be bad if used incorrectly. Take a look at SIV mode, it is a nonce reuse resistant 2-pass mode, I have my own variant which looks like a hybrid between XTS and SIV (no security proofs)

Comment: The question to ask oneself is do I want good security of the thrill of writing my own crypto system? If the first consider using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor) or in the second case take a look at the RNCryptor [Design Considerations](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor#design-considerations) and [Data Format](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/draft-RNCryptor-Spec-v4.0.md). For more depth see *Practical Cryptography* by Niels Fergusson & Bruce Schneider.

Comment: After lengthy discussion, I'll be writing my own. But I will also look more into RNCryptor

Comment: @Halen One further consideration: Since you will be encrypting many files for the long term consider how you would handle the passphrase being compromised. A good system will allow you to change the passphrase without having to decrypt and re-encrypt all the files. Consider that many files may be saved in many places and several duplicates as backup.

Comment: I will probably generate new passphrases on a particular interval, and store them securely

Comment: That will not reverse damage done from one stolen passphrase, but it will contain the damage to a smaller subset of files

Comment: @zaph unfortunately, I would have to re-encrypt all the files associated with the compromised passphrase. This is a task I am prepared to handle

Comment: It is possible to have a system where the files do not need to be re-encrypted for a passphrase change and it is not difficult. Since you want ownership of the method think about that and you can figure out the solution. The solution is similat to how you can have two different passwords for the same file.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the principle to use a common password and a unique salt per file with a key derivation function is a good and acceptable practice, as you generate the salt randomly and with the right size. The uniqueness of the salt guarantees a different password per file (actually one password per salt, so: do not reuse a salt, use a csprng).

You forgot to mention (or to design) how you're are going to protect the cipher integrity. XTS mode does not provide this property, you should add a message authentication code (MAC) as HMAC.

It would be probably better and simpler to switch to another mode which provides confidentiality and integrity as GCM or OCB. The second reason for switching from XTS that is that mode is designed to be used in Full Disk Encryption context and encrypt disk sectors and not a whole file. [some other reasons.](http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/04/30/you-dont-want-xts/)

Don't forget to store the salt with the ciphertext and protect its integrity, too.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm using the CommonCrypto library, which unfortunately does not have GCM or OCB. Would CBC be sufficient? If I'm understanding correctly, the information I have so far is that I would store the salt, IV, and HMAC with the encrypted file. I don't need to protect those 3 values, because they don't leak information. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but the IV is usually part of the ciphertext (the first block). The CBC (with a random IV) does not leak information about the plaintext. 
If you are going to use an HMAC remember that you'll need another key, you could derive it from the same password but you need to differentiate it from the encryption key. NEVER use the same key to encrypt and hmac the same message.

Comment: I don't think I'm going to use an HMAC. It looks like my process will be as follows: Choose a passphrase with high entropy > Generate a salt with a CSPRNG > generate an encryption key from the passphrase and salt > generate an IV > Encrypt the data > Append the salt and the IV to the cipher text. Does that have vulnerabilities that I need to address?

Comment: If you don't mind that an attacker could modify the ciphertext and observe the behavior of your software during the decryption (and modify one more time the ciphertext and so on), there should be no problem. If you want only to protect the confidentiality of your your files it is ok, but if you think that someone could play with your ciphertexts and your decryption function you could have a classical Oracle attack.

Comment: If your problem is only to avoid someone reading your files if you forgot your USB drive at the coffee shop that would be ok.

Comment: I will be encrypting files and backing them up (to one on-site location and to Crashplan Central). I want to protect against someone being able to read these files if they somehow get their hands on them. I am writing the wrapper around CommonCrypto and will be open-sourcing it. Will these conditions permit an Oracle attack? I'm still reading about these types of attacks and haven't quite figured it out yet

Comment: You're probably safe, but this is not the right way. The Good Thing is to verify the authenticity the ciphertext.

Comment: If I'm spending all this time researching, there's no reason in cutting myself short. I understand that HMAC's cannot use the same encryption key. I would then use an HMAC algorithm to compute the HMAC from a new encryption key. Would I then append that result to the end of the cipher text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34253/discussion-between-ddddavidee-and-halen).